# Make and change TableLayoutPanel at runtime in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I would like to know how to make and change a TableLayoutPanel at runtime in VB.NET, WinForms.

I've had a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) but I can't seem to understand how to vary the number of columns/rows (ie create new ones) nor how to change the values of any of the cells.

My aim is to have a 4x4 grid that contains 16 labels, whose text comes from a multi-dimensional (4x4) integer array.

My current code is:

```
Dim table As New TableLayoutPanel
table.ColumnCount = 4
table.RowCount = 4
table.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 8.0F))
```

This is based off the MSDN examples, but I'm not sure how to use the `RowStyles.Add(`several arguments`)` method. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Have you tried adding components to your panel using the winforms designer inside visual studio? The produced code might help you to adapt it to your needs

Comment: if you know it is 4x4, add it as a design time component and set the layout and properties in the property pane

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to change the text inside each box. Any ideas on how to? Do I need to add a label inside each box?

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the advice, but I try to see if I can possibly put everything I use in my programs inside the actual code, so the designer is actually blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will create a `TableLayoutPanel` and all labels at run time. It is fully adjustable, in that you have have a 2 dimensional array of any size and it will display all values within that array. Using this code example should show you how to add rows and columns to a `TableLayoutPanel` dynamically at runtime.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Friend WithEvents TableLayout As TableLayoutPanel
    Private DataArray(,) As Integer = New Integer(3, 3) {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Me.AutoSize = True
        TableLayout = New TableLayoutPanel
        With TableLayout
            .Name = "tableLayout"
            .Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            .ColumnCount = 0
            .RowCount = 0
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
            .AutoSize = True
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(TableLayout)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        For x = LBound(DataArray, 1) To UBound(DataArray, 1)
            Me.TableLayout.ColumnCount += 1
            Me.TableLayout.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
            For y = LBound(DataArray, 2) To UBound(DataArray, 2)
                If y = LBound(DataArray, 2) Then
                    Me.TableLayout.RowCount += 1
                    Me.TableLayout.RowStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
                End If

                Dim lbl = New Label
                With lbl
                    .Name = "lbl" & x & y
                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    .Text = "Value: " & DataArray.GetValue(x, y)
                    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                    .AutoSize = True
                End With
                Me.TableLayout.Controls.Add(lbl, y, x)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to create a TableLayoutPanel using Designer and after that to check the auto generated code in Designer.cs (Designer.vb in your case) class. Here small example in C#:

```
// tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(252, 75);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 4;
```

To add Controls to your TableLayout use it Controls property. For example:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "Hello!";
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label, 0, 0);

    }

enter code here
```